# A (simple) Measure Theory Problem

Tags: measure-theory

This question is wasting way too much of my time. Here goes:

Suppose that $\{A_i\}_1^5$ are measurable subsets of [0,1] with the property that almost every $x \in [0,1]$ belongs to at least four of the subsets (equivalently, $x$ is left out of at most one of them). Prove that at least one of the subsets as measure greater than or equal to $4/5$

My intuitions are to use finite sub-additivity, properties of complementation, and/or proof by contradiction but I've been stumped for too long. I've also tried simplifying to three subsets with no luck.

Help!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use indicator functions. The given condition tells you that $\sum_{i=1}^5 {\bf 1}_{A_i}\geq 4$ almost everywhere, so integrating with respect to $\mu$ gives $\sum_{i=1}^5 \mu(A_i)\geq 4.$ Now, one of the numbers $\{\mu(A_i)\}_{i=1}^5$ has to be "above average", so for that $i$ we have $\mu(A_i)\geq 4/5.$

Comment: Damn , I knew it was a one liner! Intuition, you fickle foe. Thanks :)